# jquery remove part of href that is dynamic

Tags: jquery

In this href:

```
<a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/4_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="">Lire l'article</a>
```

This part `/ListeActualitesCarrousel/4_.000/` is dynamic and can change, I would like to remove it. Thus, the URL will become:

```
<a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="">Lire l'article</a>
```

How can that be done?

Comment: How Dynamic can 4_.000/ be? is it always a number or is it the last "folder" path you want to remove in the href?

Comment: Which components in 4_.000/ are always present? (constant length? the _ and . are always there?)

Comment: yes the _ and . are always there

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you identify the dynamic part? Is it always whatever is between the last and next-to-last "/", or does the beginning always start "/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/", or...? Also, any reason you want to use jQuery specifically when a few lines of plain JavaScript is all you should need?

Comment: javascript or jQuery this part is always a number it could be 4_.000 3_.000, 14_.000, 40_.000, etc...

Comment: oh and ListeActualitesCarrousel/ can be dynamic too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('a').attr('href',$('a').attr('href').replace(/\/(\d)_.(\d{3})\//,'/'));
```

For Multiple hrefs : -

```
$('a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace(/\/(\d)_.(\d{3})\//,'/'));
})
```

Comment: this will be a problem if there is more then 1 a-element because you will give the first href to all of your a-elements, example: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/QfeVu/

Comment: agreed ... this is a generic statement. Would work fine if you have id or select the exact element. I had put the example with ID and XGreen revised it to be generic.

Comment: i have indeed more than 1 element to replace
i have tried that but that doesn't work!
  jQuery(".action").each(function () {
    jQuery('a').attr('href',jQuery('a').attr('href').replace(/\/(\d)_.(\d{3})\//,'/'));
    });
     });

Comment: good point I have more than 1 element
i have tried that but that doesn't work
<a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/4_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>


jQuery(".action").each(function () {
    jQuery('a').attr('href',jQuery('a').attr('href').replace(/\/(\d)_.(\d{3})\//,'/'));
});
     });

ANY CLUES?

Comment: Added handling for multiple href. Just loop over it.

Comment: strange .. tested on IE fiddle and worked fine. What error do you get ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var pattern = /\d+_\.\d+\//im,
        href = this.href;
    if(pattern.test(href)) {
        this.href = href.replace(pattern ,"");
    }
});
```

Im guessing it can be anything like `11_.123144/` as a dynamic value at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

$('a').attr('href',function(i,h){ return h.replace(/(ListeActualitesCarrousel/)(.*?)/(D.*)/,"$1$3"); });

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/LzMse/